# How can I send emails in Django using smtp.EmailBackend without authenticating with the mail server

Tags: django, email, smtp, django-settings, django-email

Is there a way to explicitly tell Django not to authenticate with the mail server when sending the emails.

I am currently using the following settings in my settings.py for sending emails.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'my-mail-server'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
```

Please not that I have no `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` and the smtp mail server I am using doesn't require clients to authenticate

Edit:
When I use those settings I get this error

```
smtp.SMTPSenderRefused: Client was not authenticated
```

Comment: No, you get that error because your server requires authentication.

Comment: I do not think so ....

Answer (score 3):

If server does not require authentication, for example Gmail SMTP relay (authenticate by IP), you need to skip authentication step.

If you are using `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend` you can find in it's code:

```
if self.username and self.password:
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
```

It means if your username or password is empty, EmailBackend will skip authentication on the server.

So, you need to keep `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` empty or do not specify them at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use console banked.

It writes e-mails to standard out instead of sending them.

just refer this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#console-backend)

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

This backend is not intended for use in production – it is provided as a convenience that can be used during development.

Also python has this in-build smtp server [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#module-smtplib)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am interested in sending emails instead of logging them on the console thats why I am using the `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a Gmail account. For that, had to add in your settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'tiagomartinsperes@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

Then, needed to make sure that my Gmail account allows apps send emails on my behalf.

From Gmail, click in the upper right icon with the Picture

[image: Gmail's upper right icon]

and then go to "Manage your Google Account".

[image: Manage your Google Account]

In there, click in "App Passwords", click in the dropdown "Select app" and select "Other (Custom name).

[image: App passwords]

Give the name of your app and this will generate a password. Copy that and paste in `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'` in your settings.py.

[image: App passwords password generated]

And the app appears in the list then

[image: App password new app]

You can delete this anytime you don't want anymore.

Then if you test again, the app should send emails just fine.

[image: Send emails with Django and Gmail]

---

Even though I've used the specific case of Gmail here, similar procedure would have to be applied to other apps like [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/).

---

If you're running a **development environment**, you have other options, namely

- save the file to console using `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`.
- save the file to a specific folder using `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'` and adding the path `EMAIL_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','media','email')` (this will save in static/media/email).
- save the file tp a special attribute of django.core.mail (which is what Djano's test runner automatically uses for testing) using `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'`
- use dummy backend which does nothing to your messages using `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'`.

Note that as we can read in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/), these options are

> not intended for use in production – it is provided as a convenience
> that can be used during development